# jquery ui datepicker issue when try to print selected date in dd/mm/yy format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

After selecting a date in jqueryUI datepicker, I need to print the date in dd/mm/yy format.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', onSelect: function() {  console.log(  $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy',  $(this).datepicker("getDate"))  ); }} );
```

How can I made this?

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does it not work? Explain the error you get

Comment: Error: uncaught exception: Missing number at position 0

Comment: Thanks, I tried it in a fiddle, see my answer for update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {  console.log(  dateText  ); }} );​
```

Note the use of the parameters in the onSelect function.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dXaAd/1/

Comment: Yeah thank you so much! This works perfectly! I don't understand the reason why my code doesn't work anyway! Thank you anymore, if you want you can vote for my question!